# Getting Django to rollback the default open transaction instead of committing

Tags: django, transactions

I'm managing the transactions for all my data-modifying tasks myself, adding things like retries on deadlocks, lock timeouts, etc.

I don't want any code (accidentally or not) from being able to edit data outside of my management code. Ideally, I'd use Django's open transaction to wrap all the read operations, and I'll manage the rest. However, this open transaction is *committed* instead of *rolled back* whenever a new "write" transaction is opened.

Is there any way to get Django to always rollback the basic open transaction, so the only data that is committed to the DB is data that I have managed?

I should also note that my project isn't always run within a HTTP request, so managing things with middleware won't be possible.

Comment: Guess you should evaluate if you want to develop something like that already for Django 1.6 as the transaction management will differ a lot from the older versions (also eg. the decorators wont work anymore). http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/db/transactions.html

Comment: Oh I didn't know about 1.6's transaction changes. Much simplified! I've [posted a summary](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/django-users/qdZ6KC2jFm8) of what I understand to be the state of transactions in 1.5 and 1.6 on the Django mailing list. I'd be grateful if you could take a look. I think there's a few things I'm unsure about, but after I get a solid understanding of things I'll probably adjust this question, or post what I've learnt back on Stack Overflow incase someone else could benefit from it.

Comment: At Djangocon Europe last week there was a quite good talk about this... I'm sure there will be videos up within the next days--it's a  must watch if you're looking for information on this :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the heads up! I'll make sure to keep an eye out for when they release the videos.